# Color or Colour Table Based on the Cell Value for a Specific Column Only

Tags: tables, color

I am new to latex and struggling with the concepts of how to colour cells in a table based on the cell value for a specific column only. I am creating a latex template that will be used for an internal audit report where there will be series of  sections and an associated table of findings, I would like to colour the last column only based on potentially 4 possible predefined values such as implemented, not implemented, not assessed...

If anyone is able to please point me the right direction I would appreciate it. The examples I  found all apply to numerals and I dont understand enough at this point in my learning to build off the examples for text characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Dog House }

Summary that describes the state of the dog house.

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Control No & Control Description & Finding \\
 43 & The cat sat on the hat  & Implemented \\
 76 & The dog ate my cupcake & Not Implemented  \\
 645 & The rate is a cat & Not Assessed  \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Cats House}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 Control No & Control Description & Finding \\
 43 & The cat sat on the hat  & Implemented \\
 76 & The dog ate my cupcake & Not Implemented  \\
 645 & The rate is a cat & Not Assessed  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the package `collcell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\collectcell\HighLightCell}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \HighLightCell } { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { Implemented } { \cellcolor{red!20}Implemented }
        { Not~Implemented } { \cellcolor{blue!20}Not~Implemented }
        { Not~Assessed } { \cellcolor{magenta!20}Not~Assessed }
      }
      { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Dog House }

Summary that describes the state of the dog house.

\begin{tabular}{llH}
 Control No & Control Description & Finding \\
 43 & The cat sat on the hat  & Implemented \\
 76 & The dog ate my cupcake & Not Implemented  \\
 645 & The rate is a cat & Not Assessed  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learnt a lot reading through the suggested packages and solution. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

It can be relatively easy to achieve with a couple of extra packages: `etoolbox` for string comparison among many other useful additions; and `tabularray`, which adds an option to run macros per each cell

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand\setcolor[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{Not Implemented}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{Not Assessed}{\textcolor{black!40!green}{#1}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{Implemented}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{%
                \ifstrequal{#1}{Assessed}{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}{%
                    #1}}}}}


\begin{document}

Summary that describes the state of the dog house.

\section{Dog House }
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {lll},
        cell{2-Z}{3} = {cmd=\setcolor},
    }
    Control No & Control Description    & Finding \\
    23         & The cat sat on the hat & Assessed \\
    43         & The cat sat on the hat & Implemented \\
    76         & The dog ate my cupcake & Not Implemented  \\
    645        & The rate is a cat      & Not Assessed  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learnt a lot reading through the suggested packages and solution. Interesting see the options to solve the requirement